# Extended partition table shows paritions beyond disk

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover data from a hard drive that is showing a partition way beyond the disk. Under is the output of fdisk for the device. Is there any hope of fixing this.

```
user@user-Macmini:/dev$ sudo fdisk -l
Failed to read extended partition table (offset=1943805952): Invalid argument
Disk /dev/sda: 31.8 MiB, 33348608 bytes, 65134 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c76a2

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         42457088 1943748607 1901291520 906.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1943805952 1953523711    9717760   4.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda4  *          2048   42457087   42455040  20.3G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: The extended is a container for logical partitions. But you show no logical partitions. and sda is shown as 31.8MiB, not 1TB? Did you copy partition table from large drive to flash drive? What does testdisk show. Be sure you are looking at drive, not flash drive. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & Others: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I'm looking at a 1TB SATA in a doc connected by USB. Testdisk only recognizes the drive as 32 mb so I have not run it, as per it's own warning regarding size.

Comment: Sometimes USB connection devices do not correctly recognize larger drives or SSDs. Does USB have its own power. My USB SATA adapter worked great for a SSD, but would not even power up my HDD. Can you plug it into an internal SATA port?

Comment: Excellent point. It's a powered doc however. Unfortunately I don't have an internal connection (I'm running linux on a Mac Mini 2009). I think this might be the issue.

Comment: You are showing old MBR(msdos) partitioning. But Mac uses gpt? GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT  & http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on the mac.

Comment: If testdisk will not show anything then you may have to use Photorec. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step I have used Photorec. It took overnight to recover some text files from a smaller drive and copy to anther drive. It only finds files by extension, so took weeks to sort thru text files as it found every copy saved. Or I now have better backups.